AWS DynamoDB: item gets stored twice
validator.js
exports.bodyValidator = (schema) => ({
  before: (handler, next) => {
    const { body } = handler.event;
    if (!body) {
      throw new Error("Empty request body!");
    }

    const data = JSON.parse(body);
    const { error } = schema.validate(data, { abortEarly: false });

    if (error) {
      const validationErrors = error.details.map(detail => detail.message);
      throw new Error(`Validation failed: ${validationErrors.join(', ')}`);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  },
});

addTodo.js
"use strict"

const { v4 } = require("uuid")
const AWS = require("aws-sdk")

const middy = require("middy")
const Joi = require("joi")
const { errorHandler } = require("../utils/errorHandler")
const { bodyValidator } = require("../utils/validator")
const { authorize } = require("../utils/tokenValidator")

const todoSchema = Joi.object({
  todo: Joi.string().required(),
  priority: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(5)
})

const addTodo = middy(async (event) => {

  const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

  const { username: userEmail } = event.user
  const { todo } = JSON.parse(event.body)
  const { priority } = JSON.parse(event.body)
  const createdAt = new Date().toISOString()
  const id = v4()

  console.log("This is the id:", id)

  const newTodo = {
    id,
    userEmail,
    todo,
    priority,
    createdAt,
    completed: false
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    Item: newTodo
  }
  
  console.log("Saving new todo:", newTodo);

  await dynamo.put(params).promise()

  console.log("New todo successfully saved:", newTodo);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(newTodo),
  };

}).use(authorize())
  .use(bodyValidator(todoSchema))
  .use(errorHandler());

  module.exports = {
    handler: addTodo
  }

Hello guys, I have the following question: For some reason the function "addTodo" stores the item twice into the AWS DynamoDB table (in case of a successful validation). If the validation throws an error, one instance of the item still gets stored into the database (although it should not be stored in this case). Can someone find a reason for this weird behaviour?

Are you calling the function twice?

What evidence do you have that the item is stored twice?

No, I'm just calling this function once through postman

I saw it in the aws dynamodb console

Supplement the debug logging in your code and then review the logs after invoking your function. If you need more help, add the logs to your question so we can see what is actually executing.
